# Hochschild cohomology of de Rham algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

I am interested in the relation between the Hochschild cohomology of the de Rham algebra on a manifold and the de Rham cohomology.

As we know, we can always take the de Rham algebra as a D.G.A. or $A_\infty$ algebra, then consider its Hochschild cohomology. But what is the relation with the de Rham cohomology itself?

Any references will be appreciated!

Comment: For any commutative dga $A$, we always have an inclusion $H_*(A)$ \to $HH^*(A)$. If $M$ is simply connected HH^*(C^*(M)) is isomorphic to H_*(LM)(shifted by the dimension). The inclusion of $H^*(M) \cong H_*(M)[dim M]$ is the one coming from taking constant loops and is a ring map for the string product of Chas and Sullivan. You can have look at work by Jones and Goodwillie from the 80's or a survey paper by Cohen and Voronov on string topology.

Comment: Great, nice to see you here again! I am reading this one: http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9709043. Something maybe related..

Comment: By the way, do you know is there any product or ring structure on Hochschild cohomology of A-infinity algebra? @DanielPomerleano

Comment: Sure, there is the cup product you can find it in any text describing $HH^*(A)$ (basically, up to sign it is kind of the obvious thing you could do to multiply two HH^* chains). It makes $HH^*$ into a graded commutative ring, which is non-trivial.

Comment: ok.. i see.. i find that in fooo's toric paper.. thanks @DanielPomerleano